# Run ASP.Net Core API on Ubuntu Server in background

Tags: ubuntu, background, asp.net-core-webapi, host

I have a self-contained ASP.Net Core Web API on my external Ubuntu server. I access the server through PuTTY using SSH from Windows 7. Now when I run it, I do it through the Shell window.  It then tells me the API is running and gives me the according adress used communicate with it, which works just fine. It also says I can shut it down if I hit another key. Now as soon as I close the Shell window, the API shuts down, which I do not want. I want it to keep running 24/7!

**How do I start it in a way it keeps running in the background?**